# How do I avoid grub errors with ubuntu

Tags: installation

A while back something went wrong with my dell laptop with Ubuntu installed. It got an error 17. This happened right after I was messing around with files trying to get a game to run smoothly on it but that was when I knew nothing abou pc gaming and just expected any pc game to work on any computer. I think thats what caused the error. So recently my friend wiped my hard drive clean with dban and I'm thinking about doing a clean install of Ubuntu alone because I actually liked it for internet browsing and Libre word. Plus I don't have any money to get a new operating system right now. Someone told me to get an illegal version of windows xp or windows 7 but I'm paranoid about viruses and it not working properly. I'm just wondering if the grub errors are common with Ubuntu. I'm hoping that they're not common and easy to avoid. And I'm hoping that the last error was because I was screwing around with it. Because I don't want to deal with errors this second time I install it.

Comment: Grub errors are very rare. Do not edit system files without without understanding what you are doing. If you have a problem, ask.

Comment: Thank you. I will definitely not mess with anything this time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

GRUB2 (the current version of GRUB) is very stable, and very unlikely to cause trouble, unless you go trying to 'improve' it. I'd just reinstall the Ubuntu of your choice and if you have problems, let us know.

Comment: Nice. This time I'm not going to mess around with the system files until I know what I'm doing. I was such a retard trying to run Protoype on my low spec laptop. I'm only going to be using that laptop for homework and internet browsing though. So I should be fine.